# VBA - Selecionar um arquivo para anexar no email

Tags: vba, excel-vba, internet-explorer

Bom dia Senhores e Senhoras, está é minha primeira pergunta. Nunca fiz, pois sempre encontro a resposta em algum fórum, mas desta vez, eu perdi! Então vamos a minha dúvida.

Utilizei uma mescla de códigos na internet para criar essa rotina que entra no gmail via Internet Explorer, cria uma nova mensagem, **TENTA ANEXAR** um arquivo e o envia.

(Não utilizei envio via smtp, pois a única porta que o proxy do meu trabalho libera, é a :8080)

Para o código funcionar você deve configurar o seu email com o HTML de visualização padrão do e-mail.

Só que na hora de anexar, ele abre o FileDialog e eu não sei qual código escrevo para escrever o arquivo que eu quero selecionar.

Fiz uma pesquisa sobre FileDialog, porém só ensinam a trabalhar com o dialog que você criou e não um aberto pelo sistema.

Estou há três dias neste sofrimento!

Código que abre o IE e acessa o gmail, e realiza o login se necessário

Vale ressaltar que como a internet aqui é lenta existe um loop para esperar a página está pronta e uma função com um delay.

Para a rotina funcionar necessita adicionar, na aba referencias, as duas bibliotecas listadas abaixo :

Microsoft Internet Controls;

Microsoft HTML Object Library;

```
Public Sub EnviarEmail()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim HTMLAnch As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
```

Abre IE e acessa o gmail;

```
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Silent = True
    .navigate "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

Call WaitAFewSeconds(2)

Set HTMLDoc = ie.Document
```

Realiza o login se necessário;

```
For Each HTMLInput In HTMLDoc.all
    If HTMLInput.getAttribute("name") = "identifier" Then
            HTMLDoc.all.identifier.Value = "Meu Login"
            HTMLDoc.all.identifierNext.Click

            With ie
                Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Loop
            End With

            Call WaitAFewSeconds(2)

            For Each HTMLElement In HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("password")
                If HTMLElement.getAttribute("type") = "password" Then
                    HTMLElement.Value = "Minha Senha"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next HTMLElement

            HTMLDoc.all.passwordNext.Click

            With ie
                Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Loop
            End With

            Call WaitAFewSeconds(4)
            Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Procura o link para Escrever Email e clica;

```
For Each HTMLAnch In HTMLDoc.all
    If Len(HTMLAnch.href) > 16 Then
        If Right(HTMLAnch.href, 16) = "?&cs=b&pv=tl&v=b" Then
            HTMLAnch.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

With ie
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

Call WaitAFewSeconds(6)
```

Preenche os campos do email;

```
HTMLDoc.all("to").innerText = "destinatario@email.com"

HTMLDoc.all("subject").innerText = "Assunto"    

HTMLDoc.all("body").innerText = "Corpo do email"
```

Procura o botão para anexar o arquivo e clica;

```
For Each HTMLInput In HTMLDoc.all
    If HTMLInput.getAttribute("name") = "file0" Then
        HTMLInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**Exatamente neste ponto, é aberta a caixa de FileDialog para ser selecionado o arquivo. E eu não estou sabendo como escrever o nome do arquivo a ser selecionado e anexado ao email.**

```
Qual o código insiro aqui?
```

Procura o botão de enviar o email e clica para o envio;

```
For Each HTMLInput In HTMLDoc.all
    If HTMLInput.getAttribute("name") = "nvp_bu_send" Then
        HTMLInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

With ie
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
```

Finaliza o IE e termina a rotina;

```
ie.Quit

Set ie = Nothing
Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
Set HTMLElement = Nothing
Set HTMLAnch = Nothing

End Sub
```

Aqui segue a rotina de espera.

```
Public Sub WaitAFewSeconds(ByVal tempo As Integer)

Dim sngStart As Single

Dim PAUSE_TIME As Integer

PAUSE_TIME = tempo 'seconds

sngStart = Timer
Do Until Timer - sngStart > PAUSE_TIME
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Desculpem-me se fui muito prolixo!

Desde já, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Você pode usar um ShellWindows API no VBA [como nesta resposta](http://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2341), com `hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Escolher arquivo a carregar")` e depois ir encontrando os campos de Controle da janela e automatizar. Uma maneira de ver estes campos e automatizar é com [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). O problema que encontrei é que o IE trava o código VBA quando abre a janela de upload de anexo. Uma solução seria configurar o gmail no Outlook que possui mais compatibilidade, mas como você disse a porta é bloqueada...

Comment: Para obter as hierarquias das janelas do Windows e utilizar o WinAPI, sugiro rodar [este código](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=52) e ver quais janelas estão rodando e encontrá-las. Junto com o GUI do AutoIT que é didático.

Comment: Caro @danieltakeshi muito obrigado por ter respondido, sua resposta foi de grande valia, porém não consegui resolver me problema pelo mesmo motivo que você de antemão me alertou: O IE trava o código VBA quando abre a janela de upload de anexo. Sendo assim, mesmo utilizando os códigos das libs win32 ou o AutoIT para identificar a respectiva janela e controles, o código trava na abertura da janela e só volta a funcionar quando a fecho, fazendo que o retorno da função FindWindow seja 0. Então é isso, fico no aguardo de uma solução para meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## AutoIt

A solução encontrada usa o script do AutoIt externamente ao VBA, pois o VBA está travando logo que a janela de upload é aberta e só recomeça o código quando a mesma é fechada.

A mesma ação do AutoIt pode ser realizada no VBA com WinAPI ou adicionando a referência do AutoIt. Se o erro de travar o código for corrigido estas soluções no VBA podem ser implementadas.

#### Código

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>


Sleep(5000)
$hChoose = WinWait("Escolher arquivo a carregar")
$begin = TimerInit ()
Do
$dif = TimerDiff ($begin)
      ;MsgBox ( $MB_OK, "Aviso", "Sucesso!" ,  5 )
      Sleep(2500)
Until WinExists("[CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Escolher arquivo a carregar]") or $dif>20000
$arquivo = "C:\TestFolder\Bo ok1.pdf"
ControlSetText($hChoose, "", "Edit1", $arquivo)
Sleep(500)
ControlClick($hChoose, "", "[TEXT:&Abrir]") 
      ;MsgBox ( $MB_OK, "Aviso", "Fim" ,  5 )
```

## VBA

Depois o script do AutoIt é chamado no VBA antes de abrir a janela de upload.

#### Código

```
Dim CaminhoAutoIt As String, CaminhoScript As String
Dim AbrirScript
CaminhoAutoIt = """C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3_x64.exe"""
CaminhoScript = """C:\Excel\testes\Janela Escolha arquivo a carregar2.au3"""

AbrirScript = Shell(CaminhoAutoIt + " " + CaminhoScript, vbNormalFocus)
```

## Código Final

```
Public Sub EnviarEmail()

    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
    Dim HTMLAnch As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim sFilename As String, sFilepath As String
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim strData As String, str As String
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    sFilename = "temp.txt"
    sFilepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFilename
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Silent = True
        .navigate "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/eofyx79x3pkg/?zy=e&f=1"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Call WaitAFewSeconds(2)

    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

    For Each HTMLInput In HTMLDoc.all
        If HTMLInput.getAttribute("name") = "identifier" Then
            HTMLDoc.all.identifier.Value = "CONTA"
            HTMLDoc.all.identifierNext.Click

            With ie
                Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Loop
            End With

            Call WaitAFewSeconds(2)

            For Each HTMLElement In HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("password")
                If HTMLElement.getAttribute("type") = "password" Then
                    HTMLElement.Value = "SENHA"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next HTMLElement

            HTMLDoc.all.passwordNext.Click

            With ie
                Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Loop
            End With

            Call WaitAFewSeconds(4)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For Each HTMLAnch In HTMLDoc.all
        If Len(HTMLAnch.href) > 16 Then
            If Right(HTMLAnch.href, 16) = "?&cs=b&pv=tl&v=b" Then
                HTMLAnch.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    With ie
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Call WaitAFewSeconds(6)

    HTMLDoc.all("to").innerText = "destinatario@email.com"

    HTMLDoc.all("subject").innerText = "Assunto"

    HTMLDoc.all("body").innerText = "Corpo do email"

    Dim CaminhoAutoIt As String, CaminhoScript As String
    Dim AbrirScript
    CaminhoAutoIt = """C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoIt3_x64.exe"""
    CaminhoScript = """C:\Daniel Takeshi\Excel\testes\Janela Escolha arquivo a carregar2.au3"""

    AbrirScript = Shell(CaminhoAutoIt + " " + CaminhoScript, vbNormalFocus)

    For Each HTMLInput In HTMLDoc.all
        If HTMLInput.getAttribute("name") = "file0" Then
            HTMLInput.Click
            DoEvents
            Sleep 200
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'ie.Quit
    '
    'Set ie = Nothing
    'Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    'Set HTMLElement = Nothing
    'Set HTMLAnch = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub WaitAFewSeconds(ByVal tempo As Integer)

Dim sngStart As Single

Dim PAUSE_TIME As Integer

PAUSE_TIME = tempo 'seconds

sngStart = Timer
Do Until Timer - sngStart > PAUSE_TIME
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Obs.: Os tempos podem ser diminuídos ou aumentados, depende de cada rede de internet e computador o tempo de processamento deste código.