# Problema Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou com problema com o botão de salvar no IE11 - alterei o campo para a língua do programa (português) porém, msm assim não estou conseguindo.

```
Sub DownloadFile(h As Long)
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern

Set o = New CUIAutomation
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Salvar")
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
*Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)*
InvokePattern.Invoke
End Sub
```

O erro que está dando:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Em que linha este erro ocorre? E você está declarando a função do Win: `FindWindowEx`?

Comment: O erro está na linha:
*Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)*

A declaração no começo:
Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Comment: @danieltakeshi consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Um problema que pode ocorrer é o [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297839/75104). Em que a janela de download pode travar ao ser aberta no IE e um programa terceiro deve ser usado. Você possui o código para abrir a janela de download ou o link do download?

Comment: Veja também [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285588/75104) de download de arquivos

Comment: Irei colocar o código no link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308187/problema-set-invokepattern-button-getcurrentpatternuia-invokepatternid-vba    - acredito que esteja declaro sim.